# cond fails when I add a puts function

Tags: elixir

I have a function that inside it's `Enum.reduce` tries to update a Map. Now I'm not sure you can do this but when the line `IO.puts("TEST")` is on, the code fails in the next iteration after printing `TEST`. If I remove that line, the code works.

```
   def to_table({team, matches}, table) do
    Enum.reduce matches, table, fn({vteam, result}, table) ->
      %{f: lo, a: vi} = result
      cond do
        lo == vi ->
          put_in(table, [team], table[team] + 1)
          put_in(table, [vteam], table[vteam] + 1)
          IO.puts("TEST")
        lo > vi ->
          put_in(table, [team], table[team] + 3)
        lo < vi ->
          put_in(table, [vteam], table[vteam] + 3)
      end
    end
  end
```

Is this the correct syntax for `cond` ? Why this error seems so random ?

Answer (score 2):

`cond` returns the value of the last expression in each body. The code fails because you end up returning `:ok` (the return value of `IO.puts` instead of the table); you need to return the updated `table` from the first clause (`lo == vi`):

```
cond do
  lo == vi ->
    table = put_in(table, [team], table[team] + 1)
    table = put_in(table, [vteam], table[vteam] + 1)
    IO.puts("TEST")
    table
  lo > vi ->
    put_in(table, [team], table[team] + 3)
  lo < vi ->
    put_in(table, [vteam], table[vteam] + 3)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3):

> #### reduce(enumerable, acc, fun)
>
> Invokes fun for each element in the enumerable, passing that element and the accumulator acc as arguments. fun’s return value is stored in acc

One of your `cond` branches does not return the new value for accumulator. (the one with `IO.puts`)

Answer (score 1):

That is because the anonymous function you pass to `Enum.reduce/3` must return the *table* at the end.

When you execute `IO.puts("TEST")`, it returns `:ok` so the next iteration `table` will be bounded to `:ok` instead of a `map` and it will fail, because `put_in/3` expects a map.

Try to move the `IO.puts/1` above the `put_in/3` call